# Need help with C# function to translate smoothly between numeric ranges

Tags: c#, math, translation, numerical

I'm trying to write a function :
Input:
Source range, Source value, output range, curve type (Linear, smooth)
Output:
The output is the "source value" converted into the "output range"
according to the curve type.

I hope I am making sense here...

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Am I the only one not getting what you mean? Can you give an example? How is the conversion done exactly and what exactly are you inputting, and what type is the input?

Comment: If you gave some *concrete* examples of your inputs and outputs, then it *might* make sense.

Comment: Actually, the question makes perfect sense to me. It’s a simple interpolation. (Of course “smooth” as a curve type doesn’t make much sense. I imagine this should be sinusoidal or sigmoidal or something along those lines.)

Comment: well here is an example. Input range is 0-1024
source value is 10
output range is 2-0.5
so the output value would be somewhere close to 2
but the hard part is making it smooth,
as in this graph :
http://www.planetside.co.uk/docs/tg2/noderef/window_1_16_2_image_0.png

Comment: To get a similar graph, here's an excel formula for calculating the ratio, first calculate X as the ratio from X1 to X2 (going from 0 to 1), then plug it into the following formula, and scale it up to the output range: `=IF(A1<=0,5;A1*A1*2;1-(1-A1)*(1-A1)*2)`, the formula is an excel formula, but should be easy enough to rewrite.

Comment: If you want a steeper curve, here's a variation: `=IF(A1<=0,5;8*A1*A1*A1*A1;1-(1-A1)*(1-A1)*(1-A1)*(1-A1)*8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some research into B-splines.  I think those will be able to sort you out.  Or maybe a piecewise polynomial interpolation will be sufficient.    Check out "Numerical Recipes in C" for code and examples.